# Why in javascript, creating date between 1st October 1941 and 14th October 1945 adding GMT+0630 as time zone

Tags: javascript, c#, date, timezone

My Time Zone is (UTC +05:30)Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi.

For Example:

```
var date1 = new Date(1944,04,22,0,0,0);
console.log("date1: " + date1);

// output : 
// date1: Mon May 22 1944 00:00:00 GMT+0630 (India Standard Time)

var date2 = new Date(1992,11,28,0,0,0);
console.log("date2: " + date2);

// output : 
// date2: Mon Dec 28 1992 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

date1 is adding GMT+0630 at the end. But if I will take a date after 1945 then it is fine i.e it adds GMT+0530.

Why one extra hour is getting added in Time zone for dates between 1st October 1941 and 14th October 1945.

When i convert date1 in C# with:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("1944-05-21T17:30:00.000Z").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

It gives me 21/05/1944 instead of 22/05/1944.

How can i get correct Date and Time in C#?

Comment: Hypothesis, per Wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_India#Time_under_British_rule_in_India : "Briefly during World War II, *clocks under Indian Standard Time were advanced by one hour*, referred to as War Time. This provision lasted from September 1, 1942 to October 15, 1945"

Comment: C# will - assuming .NET - use the Windows TZ info (depends on version of Windows and underlying system calls), and JavaScript rules may vary between implementations..

Comment: Yes i am using asp.net mvc 4. How can i handle this with TZ info. please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- Indeed, India did use UTC+6:30 for several periods in the 1940's.  This information is recorded in the [IANA time zone database](https://iana.org/time-zones).  You can also refer to the [detail of time in India here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/india/kolkata?year=1944).
- .NET (when running on Windows) does not use the IANA time zone database, but rather the Microsoft Windows time zone database.  You can read about some of the differences between these two data sets in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).
- The Windows time zone database generally does not have the long term history of most time zones.  For `India Standard Time`, it doesn't have any history - assuming that UTC+5:30 has always been in effect.  If your application needs to know about historical time zone information, then you have two options:

  1. If you are using .NET Core, you can run on a non-Windows OS (Linux, MacOS, etc.) which uses the full IANA time zone database.  The standard `TimeZoneInfo`, `DateTime`, and `DateTimeOffset` APIs will use this data on non-Windows machines.
  2. You can bring your own copy of the IANA TZDB data via a library such as [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/).  Then you can run on any OS you want.  Of course, you will need to stay updated to get changes to the TZDB.

     A Noda Time example for your scenario looks like this:

     ```
     Instant utcTime = Instant.FromUtc(1944, 5, 21, 17, 30);
     DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Asia/Kolkata"];
     ZonedDateTime zdt = utcTime.InZone(tz);
     LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.LocalDateTime;

     Console.WriteLine(ldt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
     ```

     There are, of course, shorter ways to write this - and APIs within NodaTime for parsing, formatting, manipulation, conversion etc.  But I think you get the point.